# Can I used squid proxy, set-up in vCloud Air, in AWS instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, proxy, reverse-proxy, squid, vmware-vcloud-director

I have a squid proxy set-up in vCloud Air, which I now wish to use in AWS EC2 instances. I was thinking to create a security group using those proxy details and spin up an EC2 instance using that security group.

Would that work?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: I already have a proxy set in another cloud, and my AWS account is having trouble setting it up. So I want to reuse the already existing proxy in vCloud Air.

Comment: Seems to me the real fix is fixing the proxy in AWS. Cross-cloud proxy is going to mean a lot of latency.